# Горячие клавиши и UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `UserControl`, в котором, помимо прочего, есть `DataGrid`.

Нужно извне привязать команду на <kbd>Enter</kbd> так:

```
 <myControls:ProductsDataGrid.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Enter"
                Command="{Binding OpenProductCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type myControls:ProductsDataGrid}}, Path=SelectedItem}" />
</myControls:ProductsDataGrid.InputBindings>
```

Проблема в том, что `DataGrid`обрабатывает нажатие <kbd>Enter</kbd> по-своему и просто сдвигает выделение с текущей строки на следующую.

Если сменить клавишу, то все работает как надо.

Как добиться нужного поведения?

---

Если в `DataGrid` биндить хоткеи таким образом, то все работает, но решение ненадежное.

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Enter"
                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ProductsDataGrid}}, Path=InputBindings[0].Command}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ProductsDataGrid}}, Path=InputBindings[0].CommandParameter}" />         
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

Comment: `Если в DataGrid биндить хоткеи таким образом, то все работает, но решение ненадежное.` Чем оно не надежное?

Comment: @sp7,  Команды забираются через индексатор, в связи с чем нужно строго помнить порядок, в котором они должны биндиться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле решить указанную проблему можно по-разному, одно из решений будет заключаться в следующем:

В `DataGrid`, который расположен в вашем `UserControl` подписываемся на событие `PreviewKeyDown`. Далее, в обработчике этого события, генерируем событие нажатия на клавишу `Enter`.

```
private void OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Если была нажата клавиша Enter. 
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
         // Целевой элемент, который генерирует событие, ваш UserControl.
         var target = this;                 

         // Тип события.
         var routedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;

         // Входной источник.
         var visual = PresentationSource.FromVisual(target);

         if (visual != null)
         {
             // Бросаем событие.
             target.RaiseEvent(
                 new KeyEventArgs(
                      Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
                      visual, 0, e.Key)
             { RoutedEvent = routedEvent });

             // Помечаем, что пойманное DataGrid событие обработано.
             e.Handled = true;
          }
     }
}
```

При таком подходе, команда привязанная из вне к пользовательскому элементу управления будет вызываться, при этом `DataGrid` не будет переводить выделенную строку на следующую.

Answer (score 2):

Сталкивался с подобной проблемой. Использовал для решeния PreviewKeyDown -  определял свою логику и выключал дальнейшее наступление события KeyDown.

XAML:

```
PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown"
```

С#:

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // логика

    e.Handled = false;
}
```

Наверное, можно и для MVVM данный подход использовать.

Comment: Нет, в моем случае это не работает.

Comment: @maxwell: А что значит «не работает»? Покажите код. Обработчик не вызывается? Вызывается, но падает? Не отменяется event?

Comment: @VladD, Не работало, потому что я не догадался бросать событие как в ответе от sp7.